# A bug with renaming existing column in Laravel migrations

Tags: php, laravel, migration

I added a new migration to rename an old column. Everything seems correct in this code, for me:

```
public function up()
{
   Schema::table('reports', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->renameColumn('reporter_id', 'created_by');
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::table('reports', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->renameColumn('created_by', 'reporter_id');
    });
}
```

But then I faced an error:

```
In Connection.php line 664: SQLSTATE[0A000]: Feature not supported: 1846 ALGORITHM=COPY is not supported. Reason: Columns participating in a foreign key are renamed. Try ALGORITHM=INPLACE. (SQL: ALTER TABLE reports CHANGE reporter_id created_b    y INT NOT NULL)                                                                                                                                                                                                          
In PDOStatement.php line 140: SQLSTATE[0A000]: Feature not supported: 1846 ALGORITHM=COPY is not supported. Reason: Columns participating in a foreign key are renamed. Try ALGORITHM=INPLACE.
In PDOStatement.php line 138: SQLSTATE[0A000]: Feature not supported: 1846 ALGORITHM=COPY is not supported. Reason: Columns participating in a foreign key are renamed. Try ALGORITHM=INPLACE. `
```

Could you help me to fix this?

Comment: That's not a bug or even related to Laravel. That's the database server telling you that you can't rename a column when other tables have that column as a foreign key. You need to remove the existing foreign keys from the other tables (for that column), rename the column and then create the foreign keys in the other tables again to target the renamed column.

Comment: You are facing this because you are updating key used by other tables...Check this first.

Comment: which table you are referring with reporter_id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First drop `koreign key` on `up` method.

```
public function up()
{
  Schema::table('reports', function (Blueprint $table) {
     $table->dropForeign('reports_reporter_id_foreign');
     $table->renameColumn('reporter_id', 'created_by');
  });
}
```

Then add `foreign key` again on `down` method.

```
public function down()
{
    Schema::table('reports', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->renameColumn('created_by', 'reporter_id');
        $table->foreign('reporter_id')->references('id')->on('your_related_table')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered this too - it makes no sense, because when I use my standard SQL client to rename the same field ... it works.  But it just doesn't work as a migration script.  Thus, I ended up running the `RENAME` inside a `DB::statement` and that worked for me:

```
     /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {

        DB::statement("ALTER TABLE `mydb`.`mytable`   
          CHANGE `currentfieldname` `newfieldname` 
          INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL;");

    }
```