# how to rename foreign key in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I want to rename the foreign key in Laravel.

This is how, I have created it:

```
Schema::create('holidays', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->integer('account_id')->unsigned();
    $table->date('holiday_date');
});

if (Schema::hasTable('accounts')) {
    Schema::table(
        'holidays',
        function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign('account_id')->references('id')->on('accounts')->onDelete('cascade');
        }
    );
}
```

And now, I want to change account_id to engagement_id. How to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel :: Best way to update a foreign key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38427672/laravel-best-way-to-update-a-foreign-key)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A bug with renaming existing column in Laravel migrations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49667032/a-bug-with-renaming-existing-column-in-laravel-migrations)

Answer (score 22):

It should be something like this :

**Note : Before Renaming Foreign, You Must Need To Delete Old Foreign And Assign New One**

```
class RenameColumn extends Migration
{

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('holidays', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropForeign('holidays_account_id_foreign');
            $table->renameColumn('account_id', 'engagement_id');

            $table->foreign('engagement_id')->references('id')->on('accounts')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('holidays', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropForeign('holidays_engagement_id_foreign');
            $table->renameColumn('account_id', 'engagement_id');

            $table->foreign('account_id')->references('id')->on('accounts')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: There is an additional space after 'account_id ' in $table->renameColumn('account_id ', 'engagement_id'); it shoul be $table->renameColumn('account_id', 'engagement_id'); took me a while to find this.

Answer (score 0):

What @rborum explained requires doctrine/dbal package to be installed. Else you could directly execute sql query to rename your key or do any other changes.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to do this without dropping the column.

Very simply:

```
public $oldIndex = 'old_constraint_name_foreign';
public $newIndex = 'new_constraint_name_foreign';

public $oldColumn = 'old_column_name';
public $newColumn = 'new_column_name';

Schema::table('my_table', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->renameIndex($this->oldIndex, $this->newIndex);
    $table->renameColumn($this->oldColumn, $this->newColumn);
});
```

Answer (score -4):

You need to make a new migration with:
`php artisan make:migration rename_column`

With this inside:

```
class RenameColumn extends Migration
{

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('accounts', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->renameColumn('account_id ', 'engagement_id');
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('accounts', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->renameColumn('account_id ', 'engagement_id');
        });
    }
}
```

Then execute your migration:
`php artisan migrate`

If you do not already have it, you will need Doctrine. You can get this via composer with

`composer require doctrine/dbal`

Comment: I want to rename foreign key in holidays table.

Comment: To rename foreign keys you have to drop the foreign key, rename the column and add the foreign key again. See Vishal Ribdiya answer